# Anonymous functions in a class

Tags: php

is there a better way to call an anonymous function inside a class? Here is a simple example that clearifies what I mean.

```
class foo
{
     private $call_back_1 = null;
     private $call_back_2 = null;

     function __construct($func1, $func2)
     {
          $this->call_back_1 = func1;
          $this->call_back_2 = func2;
     }


     function provokeCallBacks()
     {
          //this does not work, and gives an error  
          $this->call_back_1();


          //I would like to avoid this
          $method = $this->call_back_2;
          $method(); 
     }
}

$call1 = function(){ echo "inside call 1"};
$call2 = function(){ echo "inside call 2"};

$test = new foo(call1, call2);

$test->provokeCallBacks();
```

*** Update 1: Please ignore any syntax error as I have written this on the fly for demo puposes. ***

Inside foo:provokeCallBacks, I am trying to call the anonymous functions how ever the first way does not works and gives an error. The second one works but it's a bit stupid that I have to use a temp variable called "$method" to make the call.

I want to know if there exists a better way to call the anonymous function.

Comment: Your script is full of errors .. and does not really clarify what you want .. can you explain more on your objective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
call_user_func($this->call_back_1);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to call an anonymous function via `$this`.

Another options is;

```
call_user_func($this->call_back_1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Being PHP loosely typed, it can't do like `{$this -> callback}()`; you have to store it in a temp variable or to use `call_user_func()` either.

EDIT - consider something like this:

```
class Lambdas
{

    protected $double;
    protected $triple;  

    public function __construct($double, $triple)
    {

        $this -> double = $double;
        $this -> triple = $triple;      

    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {

        if( is_callable($this -> {$name}) ){

            return call_user_func_array($this -> {$name}, $arguments);

        }

    }

}

$lambdas = new Lambdas(
    function($a){ return $a * 2;},
    function($a){ return $a * 3;}
);

echo $lambdas -> double(2); // prints 4
echo $lambdas -> triple(2); // prints 6
```

Comment: Smart, but not exactly what I had in mind. But still a thumb up for your answer.

Comment: That has nothing to do if PHP is weakly or strongly typed, it's just that the PHP parser is limited to offer something working straight ahead here. Also the model of the language is limited, too (I'm pretty sure the limitations of the parser have degraded the language model over the years).

Answer (score 1):

Dirty and dangerous, but you might succeed using eval..

```
class foo
{
  private $call_back_1 = null;
  private $call_back_2 = null;

  function __construct($func1, $func2)
  {
      $this->call_back_1 = func1;
      $this->call_back_2 = func2;
  }


  function provokeCallBacks()
  {
      eval($this->call_back_1);
      eval($this->call_back_2);
  }
}

call1 = 'echo "inside call 1"';
call2 = 'echo "inside call 2"';

$test = foo(call1, call2);

$test->provokeCallBacks();
```

Comment: This is really bad solution as call1 and call2 contain a just an echo statement for demo puposes. However in real example I have several lines of code. ;-) This one will go to glavić as he answered my question first.

Comment: I know, as last resort eval might be a solution, but better not use it... Or as my background tells me: Every time you use eval() a young kitten will die. :(

Comment: Still, is a thumb up going to bring one of them kittens back to live? sure hope so ;-0

Answer (score 1):

I know your question has been answered but you can try changing your approch ..

```
class Foo {
    private $calls = array();
    function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->calls[$key] = $value;
    }
    function __call($name, $arg) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->calls)) {
            $this->calls[$name]();
        }
    }

    function __all() {
        foreach ( $this->calls as $call ) {
            $call();
        }
    }
}

$test = new Foo();

$test->A = function () {
    echo "inside call 1";
};

$test->B = function () {
    echo "inside call 2";
};

$test->A(); // inside call 1
$test->B(); // inside call 2
$test->__all(); // inside call 1 & inside call 2
```

Comment: thumbs up. However I would test if the $call variable is a function before I call it.